# Galeria de imagens no React, como selecionar a imagem ativa e refletir apenas no próprio componente?

Tags: javascript, react

Salve rapaziada! Sem enrolação, segue o gif para ter noção do problema: [image: error]

Minha lista de itens está sendo puxada de um JSON, onde na listagem de todos meus itens eu fiz um map().

```
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState({});

  const handleImageSrc = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // url da imagem ao clicar
    setImageSrc(e.target);
    
  };
<>
  {data.map((dataItem) => {
   **// data = imagens, descrição e valores.**
    return (
      <>
        <Paper className="paperContainer">
          <Grid container wrap="nowrap" spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
              <Paper>
                <ul className="imgList">
                 
                **//map de todas as imagens, e a lista lateral**

                  {dataItem.product.images.map((image) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={image.id}>
                        <a href={image}>
                          <img
                            // todas as imagens tem a função handleImageSrc para pegar o url
                            onClick={handleImageSrc}
                            src={image}
                            alt={dataItem.product.name}
                            onError={(e) => { e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src = 'https://ik.imagekit.io/b0g9wlasxh/buscape-images/images_ZDQgkWoQc.png'; }}
                          />
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}

                </ul>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <Paper className="imgList">

              **// imagem que eu preciso refletir no componente atual ao cllicar.**
                // coloquei o imageSrc direto na imagem que vai ser alterada, que no caso seria bem previsível o erro, porém fica melhor de exemplificar. 
                <img
                  src={imageSrc.src
                    ? imageSrc.src
                    : dataItem.product.images[0]}
                  alt={imageSrc.alt}
                />

              </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={5}>
              <Paper className="imgList">
                <h2>{dataItem.product.name}</h2>
                <h3>Better price</h3>
                <div className="priceValue">
                  <span className="value">10x R$ 134,11</span>
                  <button type="button" className="cardAdd">
                    Adicionar ao carrinho
                  </button>
                </div>
                ou
                {' '}
                <span className="greenValue">R$ 1.139</span>
                {' '}
                à vista
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </>
    );
  })}
</>
```

Pelo fato de eu estar fazendo um map e colocando a função handleImageSrc para todas as imagens, a url da imagem armazenada refletirá em todos os componentes.

Uma coisa que eu pensei, era pegar o componente atual da imagem que eu cliquei, e procurar pela div filha (onde está a imagem maior que será refletiva).

Alguém poderia me dar um norte e dicas do que fazer nessa situação?

Comment: Você está usando um estado para todas imagens, assim que você altera, muda em todos.

Acho que o ideal, seria criar um componente novo que seria o paper, ai cada componente teria seu proprio estado, e você passa a image, titulo e menu via props. ai no map você gera esse componente toda vez

Comment: Valeu Marcos! Você acabou de clarear minha ideias. Vou tentar arrumar e jaja volto aqui.

Comment: Voltei aqui para dizer que funcionou! Muito obrigado por me ajudar, agora que resolvi estou me sentido um bobo por não pensar nisso antes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom eu imagino que seja um cadastro de produto e dentro tem uma lista de imagens onde a primeira imagem vai aparecer como padrão e ao lado esquerda a lista de imagens desse produto, ao clicar é selecionado a imagem e mostrado a foto do respectivo item, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'produto 1', 'photos': [
      'http://placeimg.com/150/150/animals',
      'http://placeimg.com/150/150/nature'
    ], 'default': ''},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'produto 2', 'photos': [
      'http://placeimg.com/150/150/sepia',
      'http://placeimg.com/150/150/people'
    ], 'default': ''}
  ]);  
  const setImagem = (e, id) => {
    const { src } = e.target;
    const newProducts = products.map(p => {
      if (p.id !== id) return p;
      return {...p, 'default': src };
    });
    setProducts(state => [...newProducts]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='row'>
      {products.length && products.map((p,i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>          
          <div className='col-6'>
            {p.photos.map((f,c) => 
              (<img src={f} key={c} className='mb-3 ml-3'
              onClick={e => setImagem(e, p.id)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} />) 
            )}
          </div>
          <div className='col-6'>
            <h4>{p.name}</h4>
            <img src={p.default || p.photos[0]} key={i} className='mb-3' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-12'><hr/></div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Ao clicar o foto a foto é mostrado no seu produto respectivamente e foi criado um campo a mais com o nome de 'default' para colocar a foto escolhida, isso é um exemplo simples para entender a separação de cada produto.

Comment: Valeu irmãozinho, já consegui resolver.